# How do I create new elements in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create new elements when clicking a button. I want my elements to look a certain way.

```
<ul id="protptypeList">
<li id="element1">
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 33%;">
  <h1>1</h1>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 33%;">
  <h1>2</h1>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 33%;">
  <h1>3</h1>
</div>
</li>
</ul> 
<div class="btn" onClick="addAnother()"> ADD ELEMENT </div>
```

My javascript

```
addAnother = function() {
var ul = document.getElementById("protptypeList");
var li = document.createElement("li");
var children = ul.children.length + 1
li.setAttribute("id", "element"+children)
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode('<div style="display: inline-block; width: 33%;">'
  +'<h1>1</h1>'
+'</div>'
+'<div style="display: inline-block; width: 33%;">'
  +'<h1>2</h1>'
+'</div>'
+'<div style="display: inline-block; width: 33%;">'
  +'<h1>3</h1>'
+'</div>'));
ul.appendChild(li)
}
```

This attempt only gives me that as text on my element.

How do I create new element that looks like the old ones?

Comment: `createTextNode` creates exactly that, a text node ... you could do `li.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "your html goes here")` [.insertAdjacentHTML documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) ... or you could just `li.innerHTML = "your html goes here"` ... or you could create the elements just like you created the `li`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `createElement` or `createTextNode` to turn a string of HTML into an element.

The easiest way to do that is to simply set `innerHTML`:

```
li.innerHTML = "<div style="...">...</div>";
```

That will just put your HTML into the `li`. If you have other content in your `li` already and you want to add the HTML, just do this:

```
li.innerHTML += "<div style="...">...</div>";
```

`createTextNode()` doesn't create an element from text, it creates a `TextNode` which is just simply text without an element. For example:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelector('div').childNodes, el => { console.log( el.nodeType, el.data || el.innerText); });
```

```html
<div>
 This is a text node
 <p>This is a paragraph</p>
 This is more text
</div>
```

Notice the different `nodeType` values. `3` is `TEXT_NODE` and `1` is `ELEMENT_NODE`. `createTextNode()` creates the first type.